# Why can I open more than 1024 socket in Python?

Tags: python, linux, unix

I found I can open nearly 8156 socket connections in Python, but I call

`resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE) => (1024, 1048576)`

Does this mean the file descriptor limit is 1024? if not, why the number is 8000+, not nearly 1048576?

But with same resource condition, I just can only nearly open 1024 socket connections in C++

My OS is ubuntu and Python version is 3.6.8

`ulimit -n is 1024
ulimit -Hn is 1048576`

I test it again a moment ago
If I set RLIMIT_NOFILE soft limit to same with hard limit in C++ code, the number of socket connections can increase to 8000+, same as Python, but can not grow any more, so what is relative to?

Code is here, the C++ server and Python server, they do same thing, listen and accept socket, count it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

#define IP_ADDRESS "0.0.0.0"
#define PORT        20004

int main()
{
    // get, set and check RLIMIT_NOFILE
    struct rlimit res;
    getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &res);
    printf("%ld %ld\n", res.rlim_cur, res.rlim_max);
    res.rlim_cur = res.rlim_max - 1;
    int rset =  setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &res);
    printf("Result : %d\n", rset);
    getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &res);
    printf("%ld %ld\n", res.rlim_cur, res.rlim_max);

    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int yes = 1;

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        printf("Create Socket Failed::%d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }

    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1) 
    {
        printf("Set Socket Opt Failed::%d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }

    memset(addr.sin_zero, 0x00, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( IP_ADDRESS );
    addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1)
    {
        printf("Bind Error::%d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }

    if(listen(sock, 5) == -1)
    {
        printf("Listen Error::%d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }

    int n = 1;
    while(1) {
        int cli_sock = accept(sock, NULL, NULL);
        if(cli_sock != -1) {
            printf("current connect : %d\n", n);
            n++;
        } else {
            printf("Accept Failed");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

```
import socket
import resource

(_, hard) = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE)
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE, (hard - 1, hard))

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_address = ('localhost', 20004)
server.bind(server_address)
server.listen(5)
l = []
while(1):
    try:
        s = server.accept()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
    else:
        l.append(s)
        print("current connection : ", len(l))
```

and this is the test client, just create client socket and connect and count

```
import socket

TEST_PORT = 20004
l = []
while(1):
    try:
        fd = socket.socket()
        fd.connect(("0.0.0.0", TEST_PORT))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
    else:
        l.append(fd)
        print(len(l))

print(len(l))
```

And all of these code I run in normal user mode, not root user
My CPU is i5 6200U @ 2.3Ghz, RAM is 8GB

Comment: Interesting question, but not a C question.  Tags edited.

Comment: How are you running the codes? As a normal user or root user?

Comment: Also share some code about how you are actually setting the limits and creating socket connections if possible.

Comment: I have posted code

Answer (score 0):

The maximum number of file descriptors that a process can have open is determined by the soft limit of the `RLIMIT_NOFILE` resource limit. The resource limit can be retrieved by calling `getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE)` in C++ or `resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE)` in Python.

When you set the soft limit to the same value as the hard limit, the number of socket connections that can be opened increased to 8000+, but can not grow any more. This is because the hard limit is a hard-coded value that cannot be exceeded.

In your case, you are able to open 8156 socket connections in Python, which is higher than the soft limit of 1024. This is because the Python interpreter uses file descriptors to handle other system resources, such as pipes, in addition to sockets. The exact number of file descriptors that the Python interpreter can use may depend on the implementation and configuration of the system, but it is typically higher than the soft limit.

The reason for this difference is that some file descriptors are used by the system, libraries, or other internal processes. When you reach the maximum limit, the system will return an error, such as `EMFILE` in C and `socket.error` in Python.

The exact number of socket connections you can open will depend on various factors, such as the operating system and hardware specifications. In addition, there may be other system resources that are limiting the number of socket connections you can open, such as the amount of available memory.